# How can i find the process name by the shell script that invokes it?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

Is there a way, I can find the process name of bash script by the shell script that was used to invoke it? or can I set process name of bash script to something such as

-myprocess

(I have looked into argv[0], but I am not clear about it)

so when I use

```
ps -ef | grep -c '[M]yprocess'
```

I get only all the instances of myprocess?

Comment: What do you mean by "process name"?  Processes have process identifiers (PIDs), but they don't have names.  Do you mean perhaps *program* name?  Would `ps -p $PPID` help?  If you are on Linux there is some `/proc/$PPID` magic you might be able to do.

Comment: By process name, I mean that if I do not know the PID of a given process it can I somehow find the PID or Process Name in Unix by the parent script that starts that process?

Comment: The program name will be `bash` (or whatever shell you are using) with a parameter of the script name.  You can find the parent's pid using `$PPID`.  Are you on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the command name of the current script that is running, use:

```
ps -q $$ -o comm=
```

To get process information on all running scripts that have the same name as the current script, use:

```
ps -C "$(ps -q $$ -o comm=)"
```

To find just the process IDs of all scripts currently being run that have the same name as the current script, use:

```
pgrep "$(ps -q $$ -o comm=)"
```

#### How it works

`$$` is the process ID of the script that is being run.

The option `-q $$` tells `ps` to report on only process ID `$$`.

The option `-o comm=` tells `ps` to omit headers and to skip the usual output and instead print just the command name.

Answer (score 0):

The parent process id can be obtained from `$PPID` on `bash` and `ksh`.  We can read the fields from `ps` into an array.

For `bash` you can try this.  The problem with `ps` is that many options are non-standard, so I have kept that as generic as possible:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -a fields
do
    if [[ ${fields[0]} == $PPID ]]
    then
        echo "Shell: ${fields[3]}"
        echo "Command: ${fields[4]}"
    fi
done < <(ps -p $PPID)
```

You have tagged `bash` and `ksh`, but they have different syntax rules.  To read into an array `bash` uses `-a` but `ksh` uses `-A`, So for korn shell you would need to change the `read` line (and the `#!` line):

```
while read -A fields
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by that, but let's go with an example script `b.sh`.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

echo "My name is $0, and I am running under $SHELL as the shell."
```

Running the script will give you:

```
$ bash b.sh
My name is b.sh, and I am running under /usr/local/bin/bash as the shell.
```

For more check this answer: [HOWTO: Detect bash from shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199893/howto-detect-bash-from-shell-script)