# Shebang ignored?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, shebang

I don't know how to better title the behaviour I just experienced. I arrived from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10771857/1521347) answer because I'm trying to read the contents of a file into a string.

I have the following script which I made executable:

```
root@host:~# pwd
/root
root@host:~# ls -l script.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 83 Mar  7 21:25 script.sh
root@host:~# cat script.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
echo $SHELL
echo "foo" > /root/BAR
echo "$(</root/BAR)"
```

Now, when I execute this using my current `bash` instance or explicitly pass it to `/bin/bash` it executes as expected:

```
root@host:~# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
root@host:~# ./script.sh 
/bin/bash
foo
root@host:~# /bin/bash script.sh 
/bin/bash
foo
root@host:~#
```

However, when I start the script with `sh` I get the following output (the file is not read) although it looks like it's using the intended shell:

```
root@host:~# sh script.sh
/bin/bash

root@host:~#
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3200146/1521347) answer I figured that the environment variable `$SHELL` may not be reliable and it turns out that's the case. When I run `ps -o command -p $$` inside the script it prints

```
COMMAND
sh script.sh
```

which let's me think the shebang is ignored?

Could someone explain to me what's going on please?

As for the file reading without `cat`, I think I will just call the script explicitly as `bash script.py` which works.

Comment: shebang is only used when you run the script as a command. If you run `sh` explicitly, it's just a comment that gets ignored.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, thanks... do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: I guess the problem was indeed that I didn't fully understand how a shebang works. Thanks for linking the respective question. I still think this question might be useful to others experiencing this behaviour.

Comment: In addition to what Barmar said: In this case, you also don't have to make it executable.

Comment: If you're asking if the shebang is ignored when you do `sh script.sh`. Then yes. You told the kernel to run `sh`. It can't also run `env`.